# replace with string present in Nth Line after a match in a line

Tags: regex, linux, perl, awk, sed

I have the script which is formatted as below.

here in my example i require to search for "`Probable Cause:Unspecified`" and once found i need to replace the line with 4th line below.

Actual output is :

```
Serial : blah blah blah
A-TYPE: blah blah blah
O-type: blah blah blah
instance: blah blah blah
fault: blah blah blah
sev: blah blah blah
Probable Cause: Unspecified reason
ack: blah blah blah
time: blah blah blah
Specific Event MOC: blah blah blah
cause: blah blah blah
Specific Problem: blah blah blah
```

and once the string "Probable Cause: Unspecified reason" if found `Probable Cause` should be replaced with `Specific Event MOC`

final output required:

```
Serial : blah blah blah
A-TYPE: blah blah blah
O-type: blah blah blah
instance: blah blah blah
fault: blah blah blah
sev: blah blah blah
Specific Event MOC: Unspecified reason
ack: blah blah blah
time: blah blah blah
Probable Cause: blah blah blah
cause: blah blah blah
Specific Problem: blah blah blah
```

please help

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: `awk '/"Cause: Unspecified"/{gsub("Probable Cause:","Specific Event MOC",$1)};{print $0}'`. it gives me same output

Comment: @Prayag  The phrase to use for replacement is presumably not always `Specific Event ...`; that's just this example. The replacement is found three lines down from `Probable Cause...`

Comment: @zdim the `Specific Event ` will always be three line down below the `probable cause.`

Comment: @Prayag  I didn't realize the comment that I responded to was from the person who asked the question!  Since in the comment you were showing what you had tried please "edit" the question and add that code to it.

Comment: @Prayag  As for the code: I take it from the question that there is a particular "reason" found three lines down, that you want to put instead of `Probable Cause...`.  That reason is _not_ always going to be exactly what it is in this example, correct?  The code you tried always puts the same `Specific Event MOC`, since that is hard coded.  You'd need to scan further down and fetch the actual data in each input file, then go back and replace it. Etc.

Comment: @zdim i am not assuming but i am much sure that the `Specific Event ` will always be three line down below the `probable cause.` and yes its not about the line ..if i may want to replace `Probable Cause...` with `Specific Problem` then also i can able to do so.

Comment: the above lines are fixed.3rd line `Specific Event` and 5th line `Specific Problem:` after `Probable Cause`

Comment: @Prayag  That is not making sense.  Are you saying that you simply want to replace the words `Probable Cause` with words `Specific Problem MOC`?  Then it doesn't matter on which line `Specific Problem` is.  If this is not the case then please re-read my comments above.

Comment: in  the simpler terms i can say i have 4 line `AA BB CC DD ` verticaclly, i need to interchange`BB with `DD` which is 2 lines below.

Comment: @Prayag Ah, I see now from your data what you meant. So are these lines always exactly as shown, for any input? So you literally only need to swap two such specific lines?

Comment: yes. but not the contents after `:..`. just the string `Probable Cause` with `Specific Event MOC` with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a 2 pass `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}
FNR == NR {
   r[FNR]=$1
   next
}
/^Probable Cause:/ {
   $1 = r[FNR+3]
   n=FNR
}
FNR == n+3 && /^Specific Event / {
   $1 = r[FNR-3]
} 1' file file
```

```
Serial : blah blah blah
A-TYPE: blah blah blah
O-type: blah blah blah
instance: blah blah blah
fault: blah blah blah
sev: blah blah blah
Specific Event MOC: Unspecified reason
ack: blah blah blah
time: blah blah blah
Probable Cause: blah blah blah
cause: blah blah blah
Specific Problem: blah blah blah
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN` block sets input and output field separators as `:`
- `FNR == NR`: While processing file 1st time
- `r[FNR]=$1`: Store first columns by key as their record no
- `next`: Move to next record
- Now awk will be processing file 2nd time
- `/^Probable Cause:/`: When we find this text in a record
- `$1 = r[FNR+3]`: Set 1st column as 1st column of 3rd record ahead from current
- `n=FNR`: Store current record in variable `n`
- `FNR == n+3 && /^Specific Event /`: When current record is `n+3` and we get line starting with `Specific Event`
- `$1 = r[FNR-3]`: Set 1st column as 1st column of 3rd previous record from current

Comment: but i guess there will be two string of `Probable Cause..` will be displayed out which is not matching with my final output as shown in my question

Comment: thanks Anubhava for the support . and also thanks to all for helping me out.is is possible to explain what exactly it is done by awk which you provided and what is the changes if i need to swap after a string is matched, like if   `Unspecified reason` is found do the swapping in that line.

Comment: I have modified my `awk` to make it more efficient and added detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

your data in 'd', by gnu sed;

```
sed -E '/^Probable Cause:/{N;N;N;s/([^:]+)(:.+\n.+\n.+\n)([^:]+):(.+)/\3\2\1/}' d
```